# How to copy someone else's "meeting attendee list" to a new meeting (that you will arrange)?

Tags: outlook

1. meeting invite from someone else
2. get list of attendees
3. create your own meeting based on this list

How to do this quickly?

Best I have so far is:

1. open existing meeting (organised by someone else)
2. "reply all with email"
3. copy the list of names in the 'to:'
4. create new appointment
5. paste the list of names into the 'to' field

Comment: Your best is what I have as well

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer outlined in the question is the quickest method I've found.